# How to get the first value of a variable in C# without using array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
Main()
{
int X=10;
X=20;
X=30;
Console.WriteLine ("X :"+X);//will print 30.
}
```

How to get the first value of X without using array.

I want the result as
X=10

Comment: Then use three variables. You can't overwrite a value and expect that the old value will persist somehow

Comment: Why do you assign new values to the same variable if you want to retrieve the first value?

Comment: int x=10; int temp = x; do other stuff for your x.

Comment: that is not workig you are assigning x 3 times with new value and you are not creating new variables

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I don't see any practical case for it.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a plate `X` and you put potatoes on it `10`

```
int X=10;
```

then you remove the potatoes and put salad `20` on it

```
X=20;
```

then you remove the salad and put a steak `30` on it

```
X=30;
```

and now you ask yourself how do I serve potatoes to your guest. You guest will receive the steak because it is the last value that you put on the plate.

```
Console.WriteLine ("X :"+X);//will print 30.
```

I would suggest to use a `List`. It would be the equivalent of a plate with a memory.

```
List<int> x_es = new List<int>();

x_es.Add(10);
x_es.Add(20);
x_es.Add(30);
```

Now you can serve whatever you have placed already before on your plate

```
x_es[0];
```

If you really want to avoid `array` or `List` you need further plates/variables to store the content temporarily:

```
int X=10;
int mem_1 = X;
X=20;
int mem_2 = X;
X=30;
Console.WriteLine ("X :"+mem_1);//will print 10.
```